# Can we find the amplitude for small oscillations for the given system?

Tags: electrostatics, harmonic-oscillator

We have a uniformly distributed(with both mass and charge) rod, with mass $m$, positively charged with linear charge density,$-\lambda$, length $2l$, with a uniformly distributed charged ring at the centre of the rod with radius R, and charge $+Q$. I drew the figure below: ( The rod and the ring have opposite charges , and their centres cooincide.
Edit: We are considering oscillations along the length of the rod.[image]

The question was to find the time period of small oscillations for the resulting SHM, I was able to do this. I wanted to ask if you could find the amplitude of the rod for small oscillations.

Comment: When you calculated the period of small oscillations, did you find any dependence on the amplitude ? If not, then the period must be the same for all small amplitude oscillations - like a simple pendulum. In this case we cannot tell the amplitude of the oscillations - all we know is that the amplitude is small (compared to $R$ and $l$).

Comment: Hi, i forgot to mention that i was calculating time period for small oscillations along the length of the rod( which results in a simple harmonic motion), and it didnt have any dependence on the amplitude, it could be found out with the constants given. Okay i understand you, I can't really find the amplitude, thanks.